# How to connect mobile device to vite with php dev server? (exposing host)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, localhost, vite, inertiajs

### Solution:

Thanks to **@parastoo** it works now. I had to spin up the dev server like so (2 different terminal tabs):

```
vite --host=HOST_IP
php artisan serve --host=HOST_IP
```

then connect with your mobile device (which is connected to your wifi) to:

```
http://HOST_IP:PORT
```

**HOST_IP** can be seen in the terminal when you run `vite --host`

**PORT** can be configured by adding `--port=8000` to the artisan command.

No additional entry in `vite.config.js` was required.

### Original Question

I'm using inertia, a monolithic approach to develop apps with a frontend framework like `vue` and `laravel` as backend. I'm trying to connect a mobile device from my network to my development server, which uses `vite` with `php server`:

1. run vite:

```
vite
```

2. run php server:

```
php artisan serve
```

The site is served from `http://localhost:8000`. From [How to expose 'host' for external device display? #3396](http://localhost:8000/admin/gallery) I read, that you can do something like this:

```
vite --host
```

which should expose your network:

```
  vite v2.9.13 dev server running at:

  > Local:    http://localhost:3000/
  > Network:  http://192.xxxxxxxxx:3000/

  ready in 419ms.
```

but when I try to connect to the network url on my phone, `this page can't be found`. I've also tried to connect with port `8000` which shows `this site can't be reached`.

Any way to make it work?

Comment: When I want to check out how the page would look like in a mobile device, I just replace `npm run dev` for `npm run build`, but not changing the `php artisan serve`. But I guess there is a way to run your frontend as dev mode.

Comment: I can run `vite build` but I don't know how to connect the device to the php server

Comment: You need to be on the same network for this to work, like wifi. Then you enter the local IP address starting with 192 (that you don't need to hide here btw) on your phone and it should be good. If you want to access it from outside your home, you will need to use a public IP address and make some port forwarding with your router.

Comment: An alternative for this is https://ngrok.com/
Once installed, run the `ngrok http 8000` command and the service will create a temporary public address for you

Comment: You don't need to do that since it's already done. But yeah, if you want to try with a module you can either use ngrok or another one similar, forgot the name but it can be found on modules.nuxtjs.org. Again, probably not needed in your case.

Comment: @kissu This is how it's supposed to work but it doesn't for me.  I don't know why.

Comment: Hard to say without more debugging/info from your side there.

Comment: Can you show us the configuration concerning vite. You should not be needed to run vite server as you are serving it through laravel. Did you run npm ?

Comment: Please don't edit answers into questions. If you want to self-answer then *post an answer*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should connect to the same network, then check your Local Ip and serve the Laravel project by:

```
PHP artisan serve --host=xx.xx.xx.xx --port=xxxx
```

** you should disable the firewall **

**updated**

Add this config to your `vite.config.js` file

```
   server: {
        host: true
      }
```

For example this is my config file :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            vue(),
            laravel({
                input: ['resources/js/app.js'],
                refresh: true,
            }),
        ],
        server: {
            host: true
          }
    });
```

Then run this command and add the host that you served with Laravel:

```
npm run dev -- --host=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

These commands should run together with same host:

```
PHP artisan serve --host=xx.xx.xx.xx --port=xxxx
npm run dev -- --host=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: The connection seems to be established (php server shows in console: `2022-10-16 16:00:00 /favicon.ico ...... ~ 0s` but the mobile device only shows a white screen. I've tested on android and iphone and both show the same behaviour.

Comment: Updated please check it @ArturMüllerRomanov

Comment: Hey it works! Turns out I had to add thee `--host` parameter to `vite` command with a specific `ip`.

Answer (score 2):

Your php terminal is running on **localhost:8000**

So you can run on php artisan serve with host.

```
php artisan serve --host=192.XXXXXXXX
```

Comment: The connection seems to be established (php server shows in console: `2022-10-16 16:00:00 /favicon.ico ...... ~ 0s` but the mobile device only shows a white screen. I've tested on android and iphone and both show the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

### *** Clarification

Given all the answers, I couldn't figure out why hot reload didn't always work. With this answer, I'd like to clarify some steps.

For a mobile device to see the page, it has to be served on a local network starting with `192.*.*.*` (e.g. `192.168.1.130`).

---

**In the first terminal**

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.130 --port=5173
```

Now you should be able to connect to the server from your mobile with `http://192.168.1.130:5173`. However, the hot reload doesn't work yet. For that, let's start the Vite dev server.

---

**In the second terminal**

```
npm run dev -- --host=192.168.1.130
```

This will start the Vite development server on the same network, but it will use a different port (in my case it was `5174`) which is fine because the hot reload works as expected.

---

CAVEAT: if you run commands the other way round, `php artisan serve` either can't connect to the same port, or if it connects, the hot reload doesn't work.

---

**

### *** Improving Workflow (optional)

I was annoyed every time typing `--host` and `--port` commands so I made some changes to the `.ENV` and `package.json` files.

**.ENV**

```
SERVER_HOST=192.168.1.130
SERVER_PORT=5173
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host=192.168.1.130",
},
```

Now to start the workflow, just open two terminals and type `php artisan serve` and `npm run dev`

Comment: It can be `192.168` or `10.0` too. Depends of your local network.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Chrome and just "Toggle device toolbar" - F12 and Ctr+Shift+M

Or both devices should be on the same network and check if firewall allows connection on 3000 port;

Comment: Both devices are on the same wifi network, still not working. Should I not connect to port `8000` (php) ?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov first step would be to check your local network to find out what you do have on your network. Check your router or any software that is able to map it properly. Then of course, you need to connect to the software exposed on a given IP + port. If you're trying to reach a Vue app running on port 3000 but just reaching the IP, you will not have anything relevant (on port 80).

Answer (score 0):

Vite uses its own dev server, so you can't just use php artisan serve. You need to use the vite dev server.
https://github.com/vitejs/vite#how-does-it-work
If you want to use php artisan serve, you can follow the instructions in the link above. You'll need to use the php server in your browser though, so http://localhost:8000/